# how to print numbers using while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, while-loop

I have following java script code segments to print less than 5 numbers between 1-10.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i < 5) {
      document.write('The Number is' + i + '<br>');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then I need print this using while loop. how can I do this?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but make sure you put this code block inside of `<body>` tag but not `<head>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let i = 1;
while (i < 10) {
  if(i < 5) {
    document.write('The Number is ' + i + '<br>');
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I need take numbers between 1 to 10

Comment: `let i = 1` maybe?

Comment: @HaoWu edited :). It's in my blood to start loop from 0 :p

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Lol I get you.

Answer (score -1):

### By using while loop, write a program to print the numbers from 1 to 10.

```js
let i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {   //while (i < 11) {

    console.log(i);
    i++;
  }
```

### Output :

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10